# how to feed DataGenerator for KERAS multilabel issue?

Tags: arrays, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, multilabel-classification

I am working on a multilabel classification problem with KERAS.
When i execute the code like this i get the following error:

**ValueError: Error when checking target: expected activation_19 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (32, 6, 6)**

This is because of my lists full of "0" and "1" in the labels dictionary, which dont fit to keras.utils.to_categorical in return statement, as i learned recently. softmax cant handle more than one "1" as well.

I guess I first need a Label_Encoder and afterwards One_Hot_Encoding for `labels`, to avoid multiple "1" in labels, which dont go together with softmax.

I hope someone can give me a hint how to preprocess or transform labels data, to get the code fixed. I will appreciate a lot.
Even a code snippet would be awesome.

csv looks like this:

```
Filename  label1  label2  label3  label4  ...   ID
abc1.jpg    1       0       0       1     ...  id-1
def2.jpg    0       1       0       1     ...  id-2
ghi3.jpg    0       0       0       1     ...  id-3
...
```

```
import numpy as np
import keras
from keras.layers import *
from keras.models import Sequential

class DataGenerator(keras.utils.Sequence):
    'Generates data for Keras'
    def __init__(self, list_IDs, labels, batch_size=32, dim=(224,224), n_channels=3,
                 n_classes=21, shuffle=True):
        'Initialization'
        self.dim = dim
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.labels = labels
        self.list_IDs = list_IDs
        self.n_channels = n_channels
        self.n_classes = n_classes
        self.shuffle = shuffle
        self.on_epoch_end()


    def __getitem__(self, index):
        'Generate one batch of data'
        # Generate indexes of the batch
        indexes = self.indexes[index*self.batch_size:(index+1)*self.batch_size]

        # Find list of IDs
        list_IDs_temp = [self.list_IDs[k] for k in indexes]

        # Generate data
        X, y = self.__data_generation(list_IDs_temp)

        return X, y

    def on_epoch_end(self):
        'Updates indexes after each epoch'
        self.indexes = np.arange(len(self.list_IDs))
        if self.shuffle == True:
            np.random.shuffle(self.indexes)

    def __data_generation(self, list_IDs_temp):
        'Generates data containing batch_size samples' # X : (n_samples, *dim, n_channels)
        # Initialization
        X = np.empty((self.batch_size, *self.dim, self.n_channels))
        y = np.empty((self.batch_size, self.n_classes), dtype=int)

        # Generate data
        for i, ID in enumerate(list_IDs_temp):
            # Store sample
            X[i,] = np.load('Folder with npy files/' + ID + '.npy')

            # Store class
            y[i] = self.labels[ID]

        return X, keras.utils.to_categorical(y, num_classes=self.n_classes)

-----------------------

# Parameters
params = {'dim': (224, 224),
          'batch_size': 32,
          'n_classes': 21,
          'n_channels': 3,
          'shuffle': True}

# Datasets
partition = partition
labels = labels

# Generators
training_generator = DataGenerator(partition['train'], labels, **params)
validation_generator = DataGenerator(partition['validation'], labels, **params)

# Design model
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3,3), input_shape=(224, 224, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

...

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(21))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Train model on dataset
model.fit_generator(generator=training_generator,
                    validation_data=validation_generator)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have the labels as a vector of 21 elements of 0 and 1, you shouldn't use `keras.utils.to_categorical` in  the function `__data_generation(self, list_IDs_temp)`. Just return `X` and `y`.

Comment: i tried that already, but my loss was going bigger and bigger. therefore i am looking for a different approach. thanks anyway!

Comment: @sebk Oh, that is a different question which is not related to the error you've mentioned.

Comment: true, the error wont be anymore, but execution is still not satisfying

Comment: @sebk your current question not at all conveys the problem you have in mind. Please ask a new question on loss not being improving. Something like this would be useful for you: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/207794/what-loss-function-for-multi-class-multi-label-classification-tasks-in-neural-n

Comment: hey akila, it is not about the loss, it is much more about how in what kind of way i pass my data to the DataGenerator. my question is about the preprocessing which i ask "I hope someone can give me a hint how to preprocess or transform labels data..." thank you anyway :)

Comment: @sebk for each image, you're ensuring that you pass the correct label right?

Comment: yes, the dictionary passes all labels for each image as shown in csv.

Comment: @sebk use binary cross entropy, instead of categorical cross entropy with the labels in the format I've mentioned in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ok i have a solution but i'm not sure that's the best .. :

```
from sklearn import preprocessing #for LAbelEncoder


labels_list = [x[1] for x in labels.items()] #get the list of all sequences

def convert(list):  
    res = int("".join(map(str, list)))

    return res

label_int = [convert(i) for i in labels_list] #Convert each sequence to int 

print(label_int) #E.g : [1,2,3] become 123


le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le.fit(label_int)
labels = le.classes_   #Encode each int to only get the uniques
print(labels)
d = dict([(y,x) for x,y in enumerate(labels)])   #map each unique sequence to an label like 0, 1, 2, 3 ...
print(d)

labels_encoded = [d[i] for i in label_int]  #get all the sequence and encode them with label obtained 
print(labels_encoded)

labels_encoded = to_categorical(labels_encoded) #encode to_cagetorical 
print(labels_encoded)
```

This is not really clean i think, but it's working

You need to change your last Dense layer to have a number of neurones equal to the lenght of the labels_encoded sequences.

For the predictions, you will have the dict "d" that map the predicted value to your orginal sequence style.

Tell me if you need clarifications !

For a few test sequences, it's gives you that :

```
labels = {'id-0': [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
          'id-1': [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
          'id-2': [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
          'id-3': [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
          'id-4': [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]}

[100100001100000001011, 10100001100000000001, 100001100010000001, 100100001100000001011, 10100001100000000001]
[100001100010000001 10100001100000000001 100100001100000001011]
{100001100010000001: 0, 10100001100000000001: 1, 100100001100000001011: 2}
[2, 1, 0, 2, 1]
[[0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 1. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 1. 0.]]
```

### EDIT after clarification :

Ok i read a little more about the subject, once more the problem of `softmax` is that it will try to maximize a class while minize the others.
So i would sugest to keep your arrays of 21 ones's and zeros's but instead of using `Softmax`, use `Sigmoid` (to predict a probability between 0 and 1 for each class) with `binary_crossentropy`.

And use a treshold for your predictions :

```
preds = model.predict(X_test)
preds[preds>=0.5] = 1
preds[preds<0.5] = 0
```

Keep me in touch of the results !

Comment: the labels are for image reconition. for example if label1 (1st digit in sequence) it means, that in the image is a mountain, if there is a 0, there is no mountain. if label2 means sun and the second digit is a 1, a sun is in the image... i hope this is understandable.

Comment: i would like to follow your earlier comment where you mentioned: start with your 21 labels [0,1,2,3, ..] and then you one_hot encode this array and you give it to your network. i just dont know exactly to shape my data like you suggest...

Comment: i found this sigmoid option yesterday late evening as well :). anyway the code performs not as strong as expected. i added batch norm, tried dropout and changed the architecture of the model a couple of times. best result of acc was 71%, which is not amazing at all... i will check my input data and hpoe to find the bug...

Comment: Few hints to improve performances : try other optimizers (adam ?), look at the train and val loss curves for a potential over/underfitting, change learning rate, add complexity to the network (more conv, more blocs, residual bloc, squeeze and excite blocs, etc), add more data, preprocess images if not already done ... 
You can share your network if you want, i can look at potential improvements !